# Installing go-ethereum nodes using docker swarm?

Tags: go-ethereum, docker

Has anybody installed and configured go-ethereum nodes using dockerswarm ? 
Appreciate if anybody could share any docs or relevant information.

Comment: Read https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Running-in-Docker and https://docs.docker.com/swarm/get-swarm/ and let us know if you have any problems after implementation

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb  My suggestion is to please read my query first . I haven't asked for configuring swarm on docker or configuring ethereum on docker. I have asked to share docs if  anybody has configured ethereum  on swarm . Request to please refrain from answering immaturely.

Comment: Docs on their page is enough to get started.  I suggest you learn more to ask better questions.  I just added a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: For everyone reading this beware of the question asking to deploy `go-ethereum` on `docker-swarm` which is not related to `swarm` in first place. @Raj, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [sample GitHub repository](https://github.com/javahippie/geth-dev) with Dockerized version of a Local Ethereum Network. This consists of a set of Docker images to create a local Ethereum network with three nodes and a monitor.